# How to Conditionally Modify XML?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XML document that runs through an entity tagging model and produces the following XML. I am attempting to take that output and reformat it into a manageable, efficient manner using XSLT.

Essentially I would like to modify the field names based on the entity type and have all of the related info combined into one section or `ENTINFO` tag. That way, it's clear when I look at the data which SSN belongs to George Washington and which belongs to Thomas Jefferson. Is this even possible in XSLT, or would I be better off writing a script?

**Original XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NORMDOC>
   <DOC>
      <DOCID>112233</DOCID>
      <FI fitype="B" xref="54321">
         <FIName>FOUNDING FATHERS CREDIT UNION</FIName>
         <FITIN>1212</FITIN>
      </FI>
      <OIs>
         <OI xref="654321">
            <OIName>FOUNDING FATHERS CREDIT UNION</OIName>
         </OI>
      </OIs>
      <Subjects>
         <Subject stype="PER" xref="98765">
            <SubjectFullName type="L">Washington/George</SubjectFullName>
            <SubjectLastName type="L">Washington</SubjectLastName>
            <SubjectFirstName type="L">George</SubjectFirstName>
            <SubjectID type="SSN/ITIN">111111111</SubjectID>
            <SubjectPhone type="Residence">1112223333</SubjectPhone>
         </Subject>
         <Subject stype="PER" xref="98876">
            <SubjectFullName type="L">Jefferson/Thomas</SubjectFullName>
            <SubjectLastName type="L">Jefferson</SubjectLastName>
            <SubjectFirstName type="L">Thomas</SubjectFirstName>
            <SubjectID type="SSN/ITIN">222222222</SubjectID>
         </Subject>
      </Subjects>
      <TXT>
        <S sid="112233-SENT-001"><ENAMEX type="PERSON" id="PER-112233-001">George Washington</ENAMEX> and <ENAMEX type="PERSON" id="PER-112233-002">Thomas Jefferson</ENAMEX> were both founding fathers.</S>
        <S sid="112233-SENT-002"><ENAMEX type="PERSON" id="PER-112233-002">Thomas Jefferson</ENAMEX> has a social security number of <IDEX type="SSN" id="SSN-112233-075">222-22-2222</IDEX>.</S>
        <S sid="112233-SENT-003"><ENAMEX type="PERSON" id="PER-112233-001">George Washington</ENAMEX> has social security number <IDEX type="SSN" id="SSN-112233-074">111-11-1111</IDEX>.</S>
        <S sid="112233-SENT-004"><ENAMEX type="PERSON" id="PER-112233-001">George Washington</ENAMEX> can be reached at <IDEX type="PHONE" id="PHO-112233-100">111-222-3333</IDEX>.</S>
      </TXT>
   </DOC>
   <ENTINFO ID="PHO-112233-100"
            TYPE="PHONE"
            NORM="(111) 222-3333"
            REFID="PHO-112233-100"
            MENTION="111-222-3333"/>
   <ENTINFO ID="SSN-112233-075"
            TYPE="SSN"
            NORM="222222222"
            REFID="SSN-112233-075"
            MENTION="social security number of 222-22-2222"
            SSNTYPE="SSN"/>
   <ENTINFO ID="SSN-112233-074"
            TYPE="SSN"
            NORM="111111111"
            REFID="SSN-112233-074"
            MENTION="social security number of 111-11-1111"
            SSNTYPE="SSN"/>
   <ENTINFO ID="PER-112233-001"
            TYPE="PERSON"
            NORM="Washington, George"
            REFID="PER-112233-001"
            MENTION="George Washington"
            GIVEN="George"
            MIDDLE=""
            SURNAME="Washington"/>
   <ENTINFO ID="PER-112233-002"
            TYPE="PERSON"
            NORM="Jefferson, Thomas"
            REFID="PER-112233-002"
            MENTION="Thomas Jefferson"
            GIVEN="Thomas"
            MIDDLE=""
            SURNAME="Jefferson"/>
   <RELINFO ID="REL-112233-355"
            RELTYPE="PER-IDENT"
            PERID="PER-112233-002"
            IDENTID="SSN-112233-075"
            SENTID="112233-SENT-002"/>
   <RELINFO ID="REL-112233-356"
            RELTYPE="PER-IDENT"
            PERID="PER-112233-001"
            IDENTID="SSN-112233-074"
            SENTID="112233-SENT-003"/>
   <RELINFO ID="REL-112233-357"
            RELTYPE="PER-IDENT"
            PERID="PER-112233-001"
            IDENTID="SSN-112233-100"
            SENTID="112233-SENT-004"/>
</NORMDOC>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Transforms the output from the NLP tool into the appropriate format for storage. -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- Create sub-tags from metadata in ENTINFO -->
    <xsl:template match="/NORMDOC">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC"/>
        <ENTITIES>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ENTINFO"/>
        </ENTITIES>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Delete and append subjects, extraneous information gleaned from party tags -->
    <xsl:template match="Subject">
        <Subject_xref><xsl:value-of select="@xref"/></Subject_xref>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Make a copy of narrative text and strip out label tags -->
    <xsl:template match="TXT">
        <RAW_TXT>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </RAW_TXT>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="S">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="extra"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="extra">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}_{@type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Append tag labels in metadata -->
    <xsl:template match="ENTINFO">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:element name="ENTINFO_{translate(name(), '-', '_')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <NORMDOC>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </NORMDOC>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Actual Output**

```
<NORMDOC>
   <DOC>
      <DOCID>112233</DOCID>
      <FI>
         <FIName>DISCOVER BANK</FIName>
         <FITIN>510020270</FITIN>
      </FI>
      <OIs>
         <OI>
            <OIName>DISCOVER BANK</OIName>
         </OI>
      </OIs>
      <Subjects>
         <Subject_xref>98765</Subject_xref>
         <Subject_xref>98876</Subject_xref>
      </Subjects>
      <RAW_TXT>George Washington and Thomas Jefferson were both founding fathers.Thomas Jefferson has a social security number of 222-22-2222.George Washington has social security number 111-11-1111.George Washington can be reached at 111-222-3333.</RAW_TXT>
      <TXT>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>George Washington</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>Thomas Jefferson</ENAMEX_PERSON>
         </S>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>Thomas Jefferson</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <IDEX_SSN>222-22-2222</IDEX_SSN>
         </S>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>George Washington</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <IDEX_SSN>111-11-1111</IDEX_SSN>
         </S>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>George Washington</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <IDEX_PHONE>111-222-3333</IDEX_PHONE>
         </S>
      </TXT>
   </DOC>
   <ENTITIES>
      <ENTINFO>
         <ENTINFO_ID>PHO-112233-100</ENTINFO_ID>
         <ENTINFO_TYPE>PHONE</ENTINFO_TYPE>
         <ENTINFO_NORM>(111) 222-3333</ENTINFO_NORM>
         <ENTINFO_REFID>PHO-112233-100</ENTINFO_REFID>
         <ENTINFO_MENTION>111-222-3333</ENTINFO_MENTION>
      </ENTINFO>
      <ENTINFO>
         <ENTINFO_ID>SSN-112233-075</ENTINFO_ID>
         <ENTINFO_TYPE>SSN</ENTINFO_TYPE>
         <ENTINFO_NORM>222222222</ENTINFO_NORM>
         <ENTINFO_REFID>SSN-112233-075</ENTINFO_REFID>
         <ENTINFO_MENTION>social security number of 222-22-2222</ENTINFO_MENTION>
         <ENTINFO_SSNTYPE>SSN</ENTINFO_SSNTYPE>
      </ENTINFO>
      <ENTINFO>
         <ENTINFO_ID>SSN-112233-074</ENTINFO_ID>
         <ENTINFO_TYPE>SSN</ENTINFO_TYPE>
         <ENTINFO_NORM>111111111</ENTINFO_NORM>
         <ENTINFO_REFID>SSN-112233-074</ENTINFO_REFID>
         <ENTINFO_MENTION>social security number of 111-11-1111</ENTINFO_MENTION>
         <ENTINFO_SSNTYPE>SSN</ENTINFO_SSNTYPE>
      </ENTINFO>
      <ENTINFO>
         <ENTINFO_ID>PER-112233-001</ENTINFO_ID>
         <ENTINFO_TYPE>PERSON</ENTINFO_TYPE>
         <ENTINFO_NORM>Washington, George</ENTINFO_NORM>
         <ENTINFO_REFID>PER-112233-001</ENTINFO_REFID>
         <ENTINFO_MENTION>George Washington</ENTINFO_MENTION>
         <ENTINFO_GIVEN>George</ENTINFO_GIVEN>
         <ENTINFO_MIDDLE/>
         <ENTINFO_SURNAME>Washington</ENTINFO_SURNAME>
      </ENTINFO>
      <ENTINFO>
         <ENTINFO_ID>PER-112233-002</ENTINFO_ID>
         <ENTINFO_TYPE>PERSON</ENTINFO_TYPE>
         <ENTINFO_NORM>Jefferson, Thomas</ENTINFO_NORM>
         <ENTINFO_REFID>PER-112233-002</ENTINFO_REFID>
         <ENTINFO_MENTION>Thomas Jefferson</ENTINFO_MENTION>
         <ENTINFO_GIVEN>Thomas</ENTINFO_GIVEN>
         <ENTINFO_MIDDLE/>
         <ENTINFO_SURNAME>Jefferson</ENTINFO_SURNAME>
      </ENTINFO>
   </ENTITIES>
</NORMDOC>
```

**Intended Output**

```
<NORMDOC>
   <DOC>
      <DOCID>112233</DOCID>
      <FI>
         <FIName>FOUNDING FATHERS CREDIT UNION</FIName>
         <FITIN>1212</FITIN>
      </FI>
      <OIs>
         <OI>
            <OIName>FOUNDING FATHERS CREDIT UNION</OIName>
         </OI>
      </OIs>
      <Subjects>
         <Subject_xref>98765</Subject_xref>
         <Subject_xref>98876</Subject_xref>
      </Subjects>
      <RAW_TXT>George Washington and Thomas Jefferson were both founding fathers.Thomas Jefferson has a social security number of 222-22-2222.George Washington has social security number 111-11-1111.George Washington can be reached at 111-222-3333.</RAW_TXT>
      <TXT>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>George Washington</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>Thomas Jefferson</ENAMEX_PERSON>
         </S>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>Thomas Jefferson</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <IDEX_SSN>222-22-2222</IDEX_SSN>
         </S>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>George Washington</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <IDEX_SSN>111-11-1111</IDEX_SSN>
         </S>
         <S>
            <ENAMEX_PERSON>George Washington</ENAMEX_PERSON>
            <IDEX_PHONE>111-222-3333</IDEX_PHONE>
         </S>
      </TXT>
   </DOC>
   <ENTITIES>
     <ENTINFO>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_NORM>Washington, George</ENTINFO_PERSON_NORM>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_MENTION>George Washington</ENTINFO_PERSON_MENTION>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_GIVEN>George</ENTINFO_PERSON_GIVEN>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_MIDDLE/>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_SURNAME>Washington</ENTINFO_PERSON_SURNAME>
       <ENTINFO_SSN_NORM>111111111</ENTINFO_SSN_NORM>
       <ENTINFO_SSN_MENTION>social security number of 111-11-1111</ENTINFO_SSN_MENTION>
       <ENTINFO_PHONE_NORM>(111) 222-3333</ENTINFO_PHONE_NORM>
       <ENTINFO_PHONE_MENTION>111-222-3333</ENTINFO_PHONE_MENTION>
     </ENTINFO>
     <ENTINFO>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_NORM>Jefferson, Thomas</ENTINFO_PERSON_NORM>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_MENTION>Thomas Jefferson</ENTINFO_PERSON_MENTION>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_GIVEN>Thomas</ENTINFO_PERSON_GIVEN>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_MIDDLE/>
       <ENTINFO_PERSON_SURNAME>Jefferson</ENTINFO_PERSON_SURNAME>
       <ENTINFO_SSN_NORM>222222222</ENTINFO_SSN_NORM>
       <ENTINFO_SSN_MENTION>social security number of 222-22-2222</ENTINFO_SSN_MENTION>
     </ENTINFO>
   </ENTITIES>
</NORMDOC>
```

Comment: In general you can follow cross-references using keys declared with `xsl:key` and used with the `key` function. As for concrete examples, I am not able to recognize which relations there are, given the long numbers and various elements.  I guess setting up various keys should work. It might help if you can explain the various number sequences or shorten them so that it is easier to recognize the relationships.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Shortened the number lengths, didn't want to cut down on the various elements because I think they provide some clarity. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 2):

Consider XSLT 2.0's `xsl:for-each-group` to group the two persons of *ENTINFO* and *REFINFO* nodes. However, grouping is not straightforward. My proposal suggests running groups on *REFINFO* and map all information from preceding siblings, *ENTINFO*, with conditionals and help of variables.

Therefore, instead of applying templates on *ENTINFO*, run the grouping operation in *RELINFO*. By the way, phone number due to no matching IDs as posted cannot map to final XML.

Specifically, remove this template (or keep but is redundant) and retain all other templates.

```
<xsl:template match="ENTINFO">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="ENTINFO_{translate(name(), '-', '_')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, only adjust the `NORMDOC` template as shown below (admittedly not elegant but appears to work with sample input).

```
<xsl:template match="/NORMDOC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC"/>
    <ENTITIES>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="RELINFO" group-by="@PERID">
            <ENTINFO>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@RELTYPE">
                    <xsl:variable name="perid" select="@PERID"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="identid" select="@IDENTID"/>

                    <ENTINFO_PERSON_NAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@ID=$perid]/@NORM"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PERSON_NAME>
                    <ENTINFO_PERSON_MENTION>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@ID=$perid]/@MENTION"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PERSON_MENTION>
                    <ENTINFO_PERSON_GIVEN>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@ID=$perid]/@GIVEN"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PERSON_GIVEN>
                    <ENTINFO_PERSON_MIDDLE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@ID=$perid]/@MIDDLE"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PERSON_MIDDLE>
                    <ENTINFO_PERSON_SURNAME>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@ID=$perid]/@SURNAME"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PERSON_SURNAME>
                    <ENTINFO_SSN_NORM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@REFID=$identid and @TYPE='SSN']/@NORM"/>
                    </ENTINFO_SSN_NORM>
                    <ENTINFO_SSN_MENTION>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@REFID=$identid and @TYPE='SSN']/@MENTION"/>
                    </ENTINFO_SSN_MENTION>
                    <ENTINFO_PHONE_ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@REFID=$identid and @TYPE='PHONE']/@ID"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PHONE_ID>
                    <ENTINFO_PHONE_NORM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@REFID=$identid and @TYPE='PHONE']/@NORM"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PHONE_NORM>
                    <ENTINFO_PHONE_MENTION>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ENTINFO[@REFID=$identid and @TYPE='PHONE']/@MENTION"/>
                    </ENTINFO_PHONE_MENTION>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </ENTINFO>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ENTITIES>
</xsl:template>
```

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LUL/1)

Comment: Thank you, I think this sets me on a great track to start. Is it possible to do this a bit more dynamically? i.e. without having to explicitly name PERID and such.

Comment: As explained, your input XML has varying IDs with needed info in different nodes. Had all data resided in *REFINFO* nodes, the `preceding-sibling` and variables would not be needed.